# Detect rotation in UIInputViewController subclass. Keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uideviceorientation, ios8-extension

I have been developing custom keyboard extension and I need to update few constraints programatically after device rotates. I have been trying to detect user interface rotation in my UIInputViewController subclass but without success. These methods are not called when device rotates:

`-(void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>) coordinator {
    NSLog(@"Orientation changed");
}`

`-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSLog(@"Orientation changed");
}`

I've also tried to observe `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to detect rotation in `UIInputViewController`?

Comment: In IOS10 `viewWillTransitionToSize` is triggered in an `UIInputViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - those methods are not called in the UIInputViewController subclass for Keyboard Extensions (not sure about other extension types).

You need to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

For example, if you wanted to update the layout of a UICollectionView subview of your keyboard when the device rotates, you'd do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self.keyboard.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

In your case you can check the orientation of the device in viewDidLayoutSubviews, and then apply/modify constraints appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
  override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {        
       let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        if screen.width < screen.height {
            print("!!! portrait")
        } else {
            print("!!! landspace")
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple didn't provide this API method to the UIInputViewController.

You can infer the device orientation if the device width is greater than device height in `viewWillAppear`